# Integral Representation of DiracDelta

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-transforms

I would like to get dirac delta from integral definition, of course if I ask

```
  Integrate[Exp[I x t],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
```

I get that the integral does not converge because it does not. In this case I have to work with distribution rather than with function. A workaround can be

```
  FourierTransform[1,x,t]
```

but I was wandering if there is the possibility to make Mathematica handle distributions inside normal integrals

Comment: If you're looking just for the Dirac distribution, can't you just use the value at 0 of the test function, instead of using an integral?

Comment: Of course I would like to have something general. Of course if I already know the result of the integral it is easy to get Mathematic a spit it out.